# Redux: Update parent component data after child operations

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

I have some data loaded in the `store` after initial `Axios` call.

Then I render two components `match` (parent component) and `player` (child component).

This is the way to show the two components in a related way (this is a simplified example from my original code, in this example I could solve my problem in another way, but in my complex real code it is essential to do an operations in children component first):

`match.js`

```js
class Match extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
 
  render() {
    return (    
      Object.values(this.props.matchs).map(( match_id ) => {
        let match = this.props.matchs[match_id];
        return (
         <div key={match_id}>
          <p>{match.tournament}</p>          
          <p>{match.color}</p> {/* this color depends of children condition*/ }
          <div className="players">
              {match.array_players.map ( ( player_id ) => {
                let player = this.props.players[player_id];
                  return (
                    <Player key={odd_id} ownPlayer={player} />
                  )
                })
          </div>
         </div> 
       )
      });    
    )  
  }
  
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {  
    return {
      matchs: state.matchs.matchs,
      players: state.players.players      
    };
  }
  
  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      // actions
    };
  }
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Matchs);
```

`player.js`

```js
class Player extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  } 

  render() {    
    
    return (

        <div>
          <p>{this.props.ownPlayer.name}</p>
          <p>{this.props.player_color}</p>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {

  // I need to make some previous operations before render
  let player_color;
  if (ownProps.ownPlayer.name == "paul")
    player_color = 'yellow';
  else
    player_color = 'blue';
    
  // Then I Need to update parent component with children color condition
  // if (player_color == 'yellow')
  //  match_color = 'yellow'
  //    
  // Call some action here to update parent component???
  // things like these do not work: 
  // let id_p = ownProps.player.id_player;
  // state.players.players[id_p].color = 'blue'; This does not work


  return {    
    player_color
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    //
    }
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Player);
```

Then I need to update a prop in a parent component after some conditions in children component.

I've read this article:

https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html

But I don't know how to send data to store and refresh parent component before render.

I thought about calling like an action in `componentWillMount` or `componentWillUpdate` to send data to store, but I don't know if it's correct way.

Comment: if your child component receives its two props (which are its variables) directly from its parent, then why can't you compute the value of this parent prop inside the parent itself?

Comment: It is an simplefied example what put up but in my real code I need to do some complex calcs in children then depending on those calculations update the color of the parent component (match)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with calling an action inside the lifecycle, it is not recommended to do it inside the render method because it my trigger infinite actions, but in your situation if you indeed have to do this calculation inside the child component I believe you should dispatch this action inside `componentWillReceiveProps` or `ComponentDidMount`, in some situations you actually have to do it in both places.

go for it!

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) are pretty clear:

You can either do one-time ops in `constructor` / `ComponentWillMount` / `ComponentDidMount` or repetitive ops in recurring life-cycle methods like `ComponentWillReceiveProps`.

If you need a way for the child component to update the store, than you have to `dispatch` an action that will go and do so, and put it in `ComponentWillMount` or `ComponentWillReceiveProps` depending on the need, sometimes you need to put it in both.

---

But, on a side note, like Bruno Braga said, it does seem like the wrong place to put logic in. 
I would suggest to put this logic in the reducer, as Component really shouldn't handle store logic, just notify (`dispatch`) state changes.

Also, I don't think that you need to connect the `Player` component to the redux store, since it seems like each player has it's own independent instance.

What I would suggest is passing the `Player` Component a function from the `Match` Component, something like

`<Player ... onGoalScored={()=> this.handleGoalScored()} />`

and on the `Match` component do:

`handleGoalScore() {
   this.props.dispatch(updateGoalsAction())
}`

and have the logic in the reducer, the let's say will figure out what the color of `Match` should be, and, on the next state update to `Match`, because of the binding to `store.matchs.color` will be rendered as Red